How to predeploy and verify a linked library?
There are 40 zeros as padding in the bytecode compiled with the library. And when deploying a contract that uses linked libraries, the contract's bytecode contains the libraries addresses.
There is a difference between the compilation bytecode and the deployment bytecode, so when verifying, the bytecode does not match and verification fails. Does anyone know how to verify a linked library using forge? Must be considered in terms of bytecode
